# How to create 'Pardot Connector User' in salesforce developer Account

Tags: pardot

1. I have successfully installed 'salesforce-pardot' app in my developer account.
2. After installation of 'pardot' there is a 'pardot' Tab is available in app.
3. When I click on 'pardot' Tab it is asking about credential. I have tried too much but unable to get access.

(plz see the screen shot as well)
[image]
Some one please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup Single Sign On in Pardot as well:

> 1. In Pardot, navigate to Admin | User Management | Users.
> 2. Select the users for whom you want to enable SSO.
> 3. From the dropdown under the table, select Enable single sign-on with CRM.

See [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_setup_sso.htm&type=5) for more information on SSO.
See [Salesforce help](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/pardot_implementation_guide.pdf) for Pardot implementation guide.